# Option selected from one of the picker view duplicates in another picker view Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, uipickerview

I've a survey with 8 questions and each question has a picker view with options loading from the server. This is in the UI Collection View. The survey works fine upto 5 questions but when we added more than 5, whatever the option we pick for the question 1 gets selected both for question1 and 6. same with question 2 and 3 which returns Index out of range error and I see only 5 answers instead of 8.
Any help is appreciated.

[Gif file of the CollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwLuA.gif)

[Errors Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyaPQ.png)

Here is my code:

```
        class QuestionCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

        // Mark: - Properties

        let reuseIdentifier = "QuestionCell"

        let survey: Survey? = UserDefaults.getCodable(.survey)


        // number of cells is based on the
        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                     numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return survey?.questions.count ?? 0
        }



     override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                      for: indexPath) as! QuestionViewCell



  let data = survey?.questions[indexPath.item]
    cell.questionResponseTF.delegate = self
    cell.questionResponseTF.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.questionResponseTF.text = data.selectedValue
}

   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
   let index = IndexPath(item: textField.tag, section: 0)
   constructQuestionViewCell(cell,withQuestion:survey?.questions[index.item])
}
        // MARK: - Helpers

        /// populates the QuestionViewCell with SurveyQuestion and style ui elements
        private func constructQuestionViewCell(_ cell: QuestionViewCell, withQuestion question: SurveyQuestion? = nil) {
            cell.questionTitle.text = question?.title
            cell.questionTitle.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.questionTitle.sizeToFit()

    //        cell.questionDescription.text = question?.description
    //        cell.questionDescription.sizeToFit()

            cell.questionResponse.frame.origin.y = cell.questionTitle.frame.maxY + 7
            cell.questionResponse.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar()
            cell.questionResponse.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            cell.questionResponse.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            cell.questionResponse.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

            // TODO refactor and remove else if keying off of "ratepain" once survey questions have been updated in the api
            if (question?.type == "number_list") {
                let options = question?.values ?? [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
                let picker = CustomPickerView(frame: .zero, textView: cell.questionResponse, options: options)
                cell.questionResponse.inputView = picker
                picker.reloadAllComponents()
            }
            else if (question?.key == "ratepain") {
                let options = [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
                let picker = CustomPickerView(frame: .zero, textView: cell.questionResponse, options: options)
                cell.questionResponse.inputView = picker
            }

            cell.sizeToFit()

        }
```

Comment: Where you are calling collection view selection method?

Comment: I've edited my code in the question. I'm calling this in the cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) method.    Thank you.

Comment: It think it's due to collection view scrolling error.I've added my answer below check it .

Comment: Problem is your `questionResponse` and `selectedCell` variable. Because your `UICollectionViewCell` is getting reused textFields value will be refilled. so as per updated @codecry answer you have to achieve what is desired.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a extra data  into model as selected value then set that value to textfield  when selecting picker view

```
class QuestionCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

        // Mark: - Properties

        let reuseIdentifier = "QuestionCell"

        let survey: Survey? = UserDefaults.getCodable(.survey)

        // number of cells is based on the
        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                     numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return survey?.questions.count ?? 0
        }

        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                     cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                          for: indexPath) as! QuestionViewCell
            let data = survey?.questions[indexPath.item]
            cell.questionResponse.delegate = self
            cell.questionResponse.tag = indexPath.item
            cell.questionResponse.text = data.selectedValue
            return cell
        }


        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
           let index = IndexPath(item: textField.tag, section: 0)
           constructQuestionViewCell(cell,withQuestion:survey?.questions[index.item])
        }



        private func constructQuestionViewCell(_ cell: QuestionViewCell, withQuestion question: SurveyQuestion? = nil) {
            cell.questionTitle.text = question?.title
            cell.questionTitle.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.questionTitle.sizeToFit()

            cell.questionResponse.frame.origin.y = cell.questionTitle.frame.maxY + 7
            cell.questionResponse.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar()
            cell.questionResponse.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            cell.questionResponse.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            cell.questionResponse.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

            // TODO refactor and remove else if keying off of "ratepain" once survey questions have been updated in the api
            if (question?.type == "number_list") {
                let options = question?.values ?? [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
                let picker = CustomPickerView(frame: .zero, textView: cell.questionResponse, options: options)
                //cell.questionResponse.inputView = picker
                question?.selectedValue = picker.value
                picker.reloadAllComponents()
            }
            else if (question?.key == "ratepain") {
                let options = [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
                let picker = CustomPickerView(frame: .zero, textView: cell.questionResponse, options: options)
                //cell.questionResponse.inputView = picker
                question?.selectedValue = picker.value
            }

            cell.sizeToFit()

        }
```

Comment: It didn't work, I still see duplicates in the options textView when I scroll down the screen. I've added my complete ViewCOntroller code in the question. Please check.

Comment: Can you show the error demo work screen then only it is easy to find a solution.

Comment: Is there a way to upload the video? I don't know if you can figure it out from the image. anyway I've just uploaded the images. Whenever I answered question 1 the same answer shows up for the question number 6. Please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: you can't upload a video,but you can upload gif file.

Comment: I've added the gif file, please take a look and let me know if you can access the file.

Comment: yeah..it is textfield after all so the cell will reuse every time this got error when you insert into textfield. so you need to add a data into model as selected value then set that value to textfield  when selecting picker view. I've updated the answer check it!Let me know if it works or not ..

Comment: I was using textView before but I've changed to TextField and tried but running into 2 issues here, as you said I've added data into model but the surveyQuestion doesn't have any member Selected value. I've added the screen shot of the errors above. Please check.

Comment: As I told before you need to add new data as selectedValue in your datamodel(surveyQuestion)!!

Comment: I've added a new structure with the data as selectedValue and pass it to the data model and it works fine now. Thanks so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues here.

- The cell you were passing to `constructQuestionViewCell` method is not you are returning. Either you need to pass the cell with address or better return the cell from the function and pass it to `cellForItemAt`.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                      for: indexPath) as! QuestionViewCell
        return  constructQuestionViewCell(cell, withQuestion: survey?.questions[indexPath.item])

    }
```

```swift
private func constructQuestionViewCell(_ cell: QuestionViewCell, withQuestion question: SurveyQuestion? = nil) -> QuestionViewCell {
    cell.questionTitle.text = question?.title
    cell.questionTitle.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.questionTitle.sizeToFit()
    if (question?.type == "number_list") {
        let options = question?.values ?? [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
        let picker = CustomPickerView(frame: .zero, textView: cell.questionResponse, options: options)
        cell.questionResponse.inputView = picker
        picker.reloadAllComponents()
    }
return cell
}
```

- Also, if question type is not equal to "number_list" you are not updating the options, as the cell is being reused, it will holding the old value.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but no luck. Please see the gif file I've attached to the ticket and also I've added my entire view controller code. Could you please check?