# Trouble animating the selected collection view cell when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This is a simple question and I can't seem to solve the problem.

I have a list of cells in a collection view and when I tap it I just want the cell to highlight for a bit then disappear just an animation for tapping.

I've tried changing the background in my didSelectItemAt but it seemed to be highlighting the wrong cell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            cell?.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            cell?.backgroundColor = .white
        })
}
```

Also tried multiple things I found from stack and it wasn't working.

Comment: is it highlighting the cell before or after the indexPath?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59064713/11016649 check this

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundColor is not animatable for any cell. One solution is to set backgroundView color and animate its alpha. You could also insert your own views as backgrounds and animate their alphas in opposite directions to create the change.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) {
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in
        cell?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    })
}
```

Comment: The animation was not the real problem. I don't know who would upvote this answer

Comment: your question sound like animation problem. Maybe change the question?

Answer (score 0):

- You can show that with the help of `alpha` property as suggested

  ```
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
      cell.backgroundColor = .darkGray
      cell.alpha = 0.7
   }, completion: {
      (value: Bool) in
      cell.alpha = 1
   })
  }
  ```